# Difference between 9 direction gods in Balinese Hinduism and other Hinduism

Tags: gods, symbolism, bali

I was at the [Pura Ulun Danu Bratan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pura_Ulun_Danu_Bratan) in Bali, Indonesia, where I took the following photos, which – I was told by our guide – represents the 9 direction gods, their color, and their weapons.

Center is Shiva, North is Vishnu, but I don't remember the rest. However, our guide clearly said Indra does not belong to the 9 gods. Later I looked up [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_directions) which seems to have conflicting information. Then there's also [Surya Majapahit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya_Majapahit) which also shows some difference.

**What are the 9 directional gods in Hinduism in Bali, and how are they different from other Hinduism traditions?**

[image][image]

Comment: I just realized that `bali` tag is probably incorrect. Can someone create a `balinese` tag for this post?